# simple select count query is taking too long to execute

Tags: mysql, innodb

Below is the table structure. MySql table contains 11 million data. All the data may be inserted into the table in one day only. 
I tried executing the below query and it took 5-7 mins to finish. I hav created the index based on the query and even it is taking 3-5 mins to finish.Index is being used.

What should i do to increase the query performance ? any suggestions ?

```
CREATE TABLE `service_collection_data` (
  `service_name` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `device_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `dataset_name` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `dataset_title` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `dataset_type` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `dataset_command` varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_name` varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `command_status` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `command_result` longtext,
  `command_error` longtext,
  `command_context` longtext,
  `collection_time` timestamp NOT NULL 
     DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  KEY `device_id` (`device_id`),
  KEY `service_tag_command_index` (`service_name`(300),`tag_name`(200),
  `command_status`(200),`device_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `service_collection_data_ibfk_1` 
      FOREIGN KEY (`device_id`) 
      REFERENCES `nodes` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Below is query is executed

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT device_id) 
FROM service_collection_data 
WHERE service_name='NOS'  
   AND tag_name='Config' 
   AND command_status = 'Successful'
```

Comment: Are MySQL indices constructed similarly to SQL Server's, where they are either Clustered:(where the data on-disk is physically ordered identically to index order) or Non-Clustered ??  If so, you should make sure that the `service_tag_command_index` Key index is clustered.

Comment: tried the above one ... keeping the service_tag_command_index index as clustered. still 3 mins time to finish the query execution.

Answer (score 0):

As debugging scenarios, what is the speed of:

1)
    SELECT COUNT(device_id) 
    FROM service_collection_data

2)
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT device_id) 
    FROM service_collection_data

3) 
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM service_collection_data 
    WHERE service_name='NOS'
       AND tag_name='Config' 
       AND command_status = 'Successful'

4)
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT device_id) 
    FROM
    (SELECT service_name, tag_name, command_status, device_id
    FROM service_collection_data 
    GROUP BY service_name, tag_name, command_status, device_id
    WHERE service_name='NOS'
        AND tag_name='Config' 
        AND command_status = 'Successful')

Other:

- Can device_id be specified as primary key (thus guaranteeing a distinct value)?
- Can service_name, tag_name, and command_status be changed to integer foreign keys?

Comment: - device_id cannot be unique. how to change to integer foreign keys ??

Comment: queries executed in the same order as u sent ... 1) first query took 93 secs and count : 2812872 2) second query took 94 secs and count : 9859 3) third query took 336 secs and count 26914 4) forth query took 342 secs and count 9859 and finally my actual query took 338 secs with count of 9859.